SignaturePad in React: Signature appears magnified and cropped when switching to mobile simulation mode
Question:
I'm using the signature_pad library in a React JS application to capture user signatures. The signature pad works fine in desktop mode and on actual mobile devices or initial component mount in mobile inspect mode.
However, when I switch to mobile simulation mode using the browser's developer tools (e.g., in Chrome), I encounter an issue:

The signature pad allows me to draw the signature correctly.

But when I proceed to display the signature elsewhere in the app (e.g., in a PDF or another component), the signature appears magnified and cropped, showing only the top-left quarter of the signature.



At first in desktop mode:

When switched to the Responsive Design Mode (aka inspect mobile mode):


This issue only occurs when simulating mobile devices in the browser. It does not happen in regular desktop mode or on actual startup of mobile devices or initial component mount in mobile inspect mode.
I suspect it has something to do with the device pixel ratio (DPR) or canvas scaling when switching to mobile simulation mode, but I'm not sure how to fix it.
Here is my code:
SignatureCanvas.jsx:
const SignatureCanvas = ({ canvasRef, onSignClear, turnOffSignPad }) => {
  const disableCanvasUserSelect = turnOffSignPad ? 'none !important' : 'auto';

  return (
    <Paper
      PaperProps={{
        className: 'signature-container',
        sx: { p: 0, boxShadow: 0.25, borderRadius: 2, userSelect: disableCanvasUserSelect },
      }}
    >
      <canvas
        ref={canvasRef}
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          height: '300px',
        }}
      />
    </Paper>
  );
};


SignPaper.jsx:
function SignPaper({ foundQuote, signature, setSignature, isQuoteAccepted, closeDialog }) {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const signPadRef = useRef(null);

  const turnOffSignPad = isQuoteAccepted;

  useEffect(() => {
    const resizeCanvas = () => {
      const canvas = canvasRef.current;
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      const ratio = Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);

      canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
      canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
      context.scale(ratio, ratio);

      if (signature) {
        signPadRef.current.fromDataURL(signature);
      } else {
        clearSign();
        closeDialog();
      }
    };

    if (!signPadRef.current) {
      signPadRef.current = new SignaturePad(canvasRef.current);
    }

    resizeCanvas();

    if (turnOffSignPad) {
      signPadRef.current.off();
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
    signPadRef.current.addEventListener('endStroke', saveSignature);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
      signPadRef.current.removeEventListener('endStroke', saveSignature);
    };
  }, []);

  const clearSign = () => {
    if (signPadRef.current && signature !== null) {
      signPadRef.current.clear();
      setSignature(null);
    }
  };

  const saveSignature = () => {
    if (signPadRef.current && !signPadRef.current.isEmpty()) {
      const signData = signPadRef.current.toDataURL('image/svg+xml');
      setSignature(signData);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Paper>
      <SignatureCanvas
        canvasRef={canvasRef}
        onSignClear={clearSign}
        turnOffSignPad={turnOffSignPad}
      />
    </Paper>
  );
}



Questions:

Why does the signature appear magnified and cropped when switching to mobile simulation mode in the browser's developer tools?

How can I fix this issue so that the signature displays correctly in all modes, including mobile simulation mode?



Temporary Fix Implemented:
I have temporarily fixed the issue by implementing a workaround that involves debouncing the rendering of the SignPaper component from its parent component whenever the window is resized. Here's the code snippet:
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

// ...

const [renderSignPad, setRenderSignPad] = useState(true);

const debouncedRenderSignPad = () => {
  return debounce(() => {
    setRenderSignPad(true);
  }, 500);
};

const handleRenderSignPad = () => {
  if (renderSignPad) {
    setTimeout(() => setRenderSignPad(false), 100);
  }

  debouncedRenderSignPad()();
};

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('resize', handleRenderSignPad);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', handleRenderSignPad);
  };
}, []);

return (
  <Stack spacing={4} sx={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: containerMaxWidth }}>
    <QuoteDetails />
    <CostsTable />
    <GrandTotal />
    {renderSignPad && (
      <SignPaper
        foundQuote={foundQuote}
        signature={signature}
        setSignature={setSignature}
        isQuoteAccepted={isQuoteAccepted}
        closeDialog={closeDialog}
      />
    )}
  </Stack>
);


Note:

Hacky Solution:

I acknowledge that this is a hacky workaround.
Users are generally not expected to manipulate the app through the browser's inspect tool.
However, in case they do, this fix ensures that there is no problem with the important signature.




Still Seeking a Proper Solution:

I'm still looking for a proper solution to this issue that doesn't rely on unmounting and remounting components or using debounced functions.
Ideally, the canvas scaling and device pixel ratio should be handled correctly within the SignPaper and SignatureCanvas components.



